# what is the graph of $y = x^x$?

Tags: functions

Obviously on the RHS this graph is just a really steep exponential graph however problems arise on the LHS and I cannot find any graph sketching programs that can do. Some will give a graph but then simply say that the LHS is undefined which must be incorrect since negative values with odd powers must still work like $-3^{-3} = -1/27$ but then of course values like $(-1/2)^{-1/2}$ do not. I asked my maths teacher about this and my tutor and both didn't seem to have answers.

Comment: Do you known what is the definition of $x^x$?

Comment: You might want to see [this](http://www.peda.com/grafeq/gallery/rogue/xx_exponential.html).

Comment: You are failing to distinguish between $(-1/2)^{-1/2}$ and $-1/2^{-1/2}$.  The latter means $-1/(2^{-1/2})$, which is the same as $-(1/2)^{-1/2}$, but different from $(-1/2)^{-1/2}$. $\qquad$

Comment: Note that on the interval $0<x<\text{a certain positive number}$, $x^x$ actually _decreases_ as $x$ increases. $\qquad$

Comment: yeah thats intresting as well. At first I thought it would decrease between 0 < x < 1 but it seems to around x = 0.4. And this is my first time using the site sorry. Thanks for knowing what i mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When $x<0, x^x$ is undefined (in the real numbers) for most values of $x.$  It is defined for negative odd integers.

However in the complex numbers $x^x$ is defined for negative values of $x.$  It is essentially a spiral in the complex plane, touching the real axis when $x$ is a negative odd integer.

Comment: [Apropos.](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/10598)

Comment: Yeah that sounds pretty cool. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, $(-3)^{-3}$ can be defined, but problems arise when you try to calculate rational powers of some negative value. For instance, think of $(-\frac{1}{2})^{-1/2}$. This can be written as $\sqrt{-2}$. As you can see, this is not a real value. This is why most graph sketching programs don't give us the graph for $x<0$.

Comment: oh yeah I meant (-1/2)^(-1/2)